# Is It A Good Idea to use oplog for versioning in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My program uses MongoDB and It needs to log all insert, update and delete operations and prints it to user. I look at the mongo oplog and it seems it provides the necessary functionality. As in advantage, it allows to see all changes made outside of my program. I see one problem that it is capped and deletes old entries, but I want to keep all history. Though I think it can be solved by setting a large oplog size and I hope the space will not be an issue.
Are there other problems with this approach?

Comment: How does oplog provide the functionality? Can you elaborate on how it can fit your purpose?

Comment: The oplog will always have a limited size. I'd log the operations manually utilizing a service layer.

Comment: @Sammaye I can call `db.oplog.$main.find()` which returns insert/update/delete operations with timestamp and modified data

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg Doing it manually is a satisfying solution, but it's not trivial in a concurrent environment. I can't find any standard solution that can be simple used in mongo, only something like this https://github.com/thiloplanz/v7files/wiki/Vermongo. If you provide some helpful links with other solutions it would be good.

Comment: It *is* rather trivial: `var oid = new ObjectId(); doc._id= oid; db.logs.insert({doc: oid, date: new ISODate(), operation: "insert", pending: true}); db.docs.insert(doc); db.logs.update({doc:oid},{$set:{pending:false}})`. For update operations you'd have to check wether there are pending updates, of course. A bit rough, but you get the picture. Will try to put this in a proper answer later this day, on the move.

Comment: The problem in a concurrent environment is that `docs.insert` and `logs.update` do not execute atomically. Log must represent a true order of updates in case of simultaneous updates of the same document especiallly if it stores a data diffs. (see my link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of MongoDB's solutions architects has written [a blog post](http://askasya.com/post/bestversion) about this. Essentially you can query the oplog and copy the data to a new collection. I guess that means its not a *terrible* idea though I can't comment on whether it's a *good* idea.